# How to validate UNC paths and mapped folders paths in Java

Tags: java, validation, path, uri, unc

I need to write in java a static method which validates both UNC paths and local files and folders (for mapped drives).
The method should validate strings like `"\\\\computer\\folder\\file.txt"` or `"c:\folder\file.txt"` or any other UNC accepted format.
What is the best way to do that

I tried to use `java.net.URI` class but that does not really validated UNC paths and local files but URI formats

Comment: Do you want to check if the strings are valid path names, or do you also want to check whether the files exist?  `Path.of(s)` is enough to do the former.  `Files.exists(Path.of(s))` will do the latter.

Comment: Hi @VGR, I want to validate if the file exists , where the path contains a file otherwise I need to validate the path exists for  either  UNC or  local (mapped drives) folders/files .